# Не получается вернуть параметры класса CSS с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код на HTML:

```js
const mainCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
const textCollect = document.getElementById('menu__text');
const collection = document.getElementById('collection');
const closeMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
arrayMainCircle = [];
arrayCloseMenu = [];

function openCollection() {
  for (var i = 0; i < mainCircle.length; i++) {
    arrayMainCircle = mainCircle[i]
  }
  console.log(arrayMainCircle); //то что добавлено для наглядности
  arrayMainCircle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(arrayMainCircle); //то что добавлено для наглядности
    arrayMainCircle.classList.add('menu-act');
    arrayMainCircle.style.width = '100%';
    arrayMainCircle.style.height = '100%';
    textCollect.innerHTML = '';
    collection.style.opacity = '1';
  })
}

function closeCollection() {
  for (var i = 0; i < closeMenu.length; i++) {
    arrayCloseMenu = closeMenu[i];
  }
  arrayCloseMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(arrayMainCircle); //то что добавлено для наглядности
    arrayMainCircle.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    arrayMainCircle.style.height = '250px';
  })
}

function main() {
  openCollection();
  closeCollection();
}

window.onload = function() {
  main();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/33ff99") no-repeat top/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 70%;
  top: 60%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .7s;
}

.menu a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -48px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .7s;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
}

#collection {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s;
}

#close {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#close span,
#close span::after,
#close span::before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#close span::after,
#close span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

#close span::after {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#close span {
  height: 0px;
}

#close span::before {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-act {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 0%;
  transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <a href="#" id="menu__text">Коллекция</a>
    <div class="collection" id="collection">
      <div id="close" class="close">
        <span class="close__span"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

При помощи JS, я меняю свойства класса `.menu`, он увеличивается во весь экран и убираются закругления, все прекрасно, но когда пытаюсь вернуть прежние параметры при помощи функции `closeCollection()` срабатывают все параметры, кроме `height` и `width`.
С чем это связано и как можно вернуть предыдущие размеры при нажатии на `class` или `id` "`close`"?

Comment: Например, зачем тебе `arrayMainCircle = []; arrayCloseMenu = [];` эти два массива? К тому же не объявленные???